# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1) when updating UIImage of UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, coreml

I am new with iOS and CoreML. I have a very simple UI with two UIImageViews (one should be the input, and the second should be the output). When tapping the first one, the image should be processed by a neural network and the output should be displayed in the second one.

However, when I try to download the image from the MLMultiArray output object and create an UIImage from it which I can then upload to the second UIImageView I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1) .

I have reduced the problem to not calling the neural network processing at all, just trying to create a new image from a MLMultiArray. The outcome was the same.

After that I tried generating an UIImage from an empty buffer. The image is created correctly, but if I attempt to update the UIImageView to use it, I get the same error.

If I try to update the second UIImageView to a different image (e.g.: the input image) everything works fine.

I assume this is a memory management issue about the UIImage object I am creating but I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var out: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func imageTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let imageView = sender.view as? UIImageView

        if let imageToAnalyse = imageView?.image {
            if let outImg = process(forImage: imageToAnalyse) {
                out.image = outImg
            }
        }
    }

    func process (forImage inImage:UIImage) -> UIImage? {

        let size = CGSize(width: 512, height: 512)
        let mlOut = try? MLMultiArray(shape: [1, size.height, size.width] as [NSNumber], dataType: .float32)
        let newImage = getSinglePlaneImage(inBuffer: mlOut!, width: Int(size.width), height: Int(size.height))

        return newImage
    }

    func getSinglePlaneImage(inBuffer: MLMultiArray, width: Int, height: Int) -> UIImage
    {
        var newImage: UIImage

//        let floatPtr =  inBuffer.dataPointer.bindMemory(to: Float32.self, capacity: inBuffer.count)
//        let floatBuffer = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: floatPtr, count: inBuffer.count)
//        let pixelValues : [UInt8]? = Array(floatBuffer).map({UInt8( ImageProcessor.clamp( (($0) + 1.0) * 128.0, minValue: 0.0, maxValue: 255.0) ) })

        //simulating pixels from MLMultiArray 
        let pixels : [UInt8]? = Array(repeating: 0, count: 512*512)

        var imageRef: CGImage?

        if var pixelValues = pixels {
            let bitsPerComponent = 8
            let bytesPerPixel = 1
            let bitsPerPixel = bytesPerPixel * bitsPerComponent
            let bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width
            let totalBytes = height * bytesPerRow

            imageRef = withUnsafePointer(to: &pixelValues, {
                ptr -> CGImage? in
                var imageRef: CGImage?
                let colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()
                let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.none.rawValue).union(CGBitmapInfo())
                let data = UnsafeRawPointer(ptr.pointee).assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)
                let releaseData: CGDataProviderReleaseDataCallback = {
                    (info: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?, data: UnsafeRawPointer, size: Int) -> () in
                }

                if let providerRef = CGDataProvider(dataInfo: nil, data: data, size: totalBytes, releaseData: releaseData) {
                    imageRef = CGImage(width: width,
                                       height: height,
                                       bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent,
                                       bitsPerPixel: bitsPerPixel,
                                       bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow,
                                       space: colorSpaceRef,
                                       bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo,
                                       provider: providerRef,
                                       decode: nil,
                                       shouldInterpolate: false,
                                       intent: CGColorRenderingIntent.defaultIntent)
                }


                return imageRef
            })
        }

        newImage = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef!)

        return newImage
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you posted only shows one UIImageView.  Did you attach the view to the gesture recognizer?

Comment: @osteven, yes, the first UIImageView is attached to the gesture recogniser. When a tap is recorded, the image in this ImageView should be fed to the neural network and the output should be placed in the second UIImageView, that is referenced via the outlet you can see in the code

Comment: This line `let pixels : [UInt8]? = Array(repeating: 0, count: 512*512)` is far from _simulating pixels from MLMultiArray_. As your `MLMultiArray` is initialized as `MLMultiArray(shape: [1, size.height, size.width] as [NSNumber], dataType: .float32)`, it is not an array of `UInt8`, but an array of `Float32`. Your code contains some mis-usages about pointers, but correcting the code using the Array of UInt8 may not help you fix the original code using `MLMultiArray`. Please update your `getSinglePlaneImage` to the version using `MLMultiArray`.

Comment: @OOPer, thank you for the comment. I was actually doing a conversion in the initial code from Float32 to Uint8. I added the initial code (commented).

Comment: @markwalberg, thank for adding your hidden code. Writing an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your code would convert 512x512-float32 array into 512x512-UInt8 Array successfully, so I write this answer based on the uncommented version of your code. (Though, the conversion is not efficient enough and has some room to improve.)

### UPDATE

The following description is not the right solution for the OP's issue. Just kept for record. Please skip to **UPDATED CODE** at the bottom of this answer.

#### OLD CODE (NOT the right solution)

First of all, the worst flaw in the code are the following two lines:

```
imageRef = withUnsafePointer(to: &pixelValues, {

    let data = UnsafeRawPointer(ptr.pointee).assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)
```

The first line above passes a pointer to `[UInt8]?`, in Swift, `[UInt8]?` (aka `Optional<Array<UInt8>>`) is an 8-byte struct, not a contiguous region like C-arrays.

The second is more dangerous. `ptr.pointee` is `[UInt8]?`, but accessing Swift Arrays through pointer is not guaranteed. And passing an Array to `UnsafeRawPointer.init(_:)` may create a temporal region which would be deallocated just after the call to the initializer.

As you know, accessing a dangling pointer does not make harm in some limited condition occasionally, but may generate unexpected result at any time.

---

I would write something like this:

```
func getSinglePlaneImage(inBuffer: MLMultiArray, width: Int, height: Int) -> UIImage {

    //simulating pixels from MLMultiArray
    //...
    let pixelValues: [UInt8] = Array(repeating: 0, count: 1*512*512)

    let bitsPerComponent = 8
    let bytesPerPixel = 1
    let bitsPerPixel = bytesPerPixel * 8
    let bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width
    let totalBytes = height * bytesPerRow

    let imageRef = pixelValues.withUnsafeBytes({bytes -> CGImage? in
        var imageRef: CGImage?
        let colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()
        let bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.none.rawValue)

        let data = bytes.baseAddress!.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)
        let releaseData: CGDataProviderReleaseDataCallback = {_,_,_ in }

        if let providerRef = CGDataProvider(dataInfo: nil, data: data, size: totalBytes, releaseData: releaseData) {
            imageRef = CGImage(width: width,
                               height: height,
                               bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent,
                               bitsPerPixel: bitsPerPixel,
                               bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow,
                               space: colorSpaceRef,
                               bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo,
                               provider: providerRef,
                               decode: nil,
                               shouldInterpolate: false,
                               intent: .defaultIntent)
        }


        return imageRef
    })

    let newImage = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef!)

    return newImage
}
```

When you want a pointer pointing to the starting element of an Array, use `withUnsafeBytes` and use the pointer (in fact, it is an `UnsafeRawBufferPointer`) inside the closure argument.

One more, your `pixels` or `pixelValues` have no need to be an Optional.

---

Or else, you can create a grey-scale image with `Float32` for each pixel.

```
func getSinglePlaneImage(inBuffer: MLMultiArray, width: Int, height: Int) -> UIImage {

    //simulating pixels from MLMultiArray
    //...
    let pixelValues: [Float32] = Array(repeating: 0, count: 1*512*512)

    let bitsPerComponent = 32 //<-
    let bytesPerPixel = 4 //<-
    let bitsPerPixel = bytesPerPixel * 8
    let bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width
    let totalBytes = height * bytesPerRow

    let imageRef = pixelValues.withUnsafeBytes({bytes -> CGImage? in
        var imageRef: CGImage?
        let colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()
        let bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo = [CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.none.rawValue),
                          .byteOrder32Little, .floatComponents] //<-
        let data = bytes.baseAddress!.assumingMemoryBound(to: Float32.self)
        let releaseData: CGDataProviderReleaseDataCallback = {_,_,_ in }

        if let providerRef = CGDataProvider(dataInfo: nil, data: data, size: totalBytes, releaseData: releaseData) {
            imageRef = CGImage(width: width,
                               height: height,
                               bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent,
                               bitsPerPixel: bitsPerPixel,
                               bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow,
                               space: colorSpaceRef,
                               bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo,
                               provider: providerRef,
                               decode: nil,
                               shouldInterpolate: false,
                               intent: CGColorRenderingIntent.defaultIntent)
        }


        return imageRef
    })

    let newImage = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef!)

    return newImage
}
```

Both work as expected in my testing project, but if you find something wrong, please inform me.

---

#### UPDATED CODE (Hope this is the right solution)

I was missing the fact that `CGDataProvider` keeps the pointer when created with `init(dataInfo:data:size:releaseData:)` even after a `CGImage` is created. So, it may be referenced after the closure to `withUnsafeBytes` is finished, when it is not valid.

You should better use `CGDataProvider.init(data:)` in such cases.

```
func getSinglePlaneImage(inBuffer: MLMultiArray, width: Int, height: Int) -> UIImage {
    var newImage: UIImage

    //let floatPtr =  inBuffer.dataPointer.bindMemory(to: Float32.self, capacity: inBuffer.count)
    //let floatBuffer = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: floatPtr, count: inBuffer.count)
    //let pixelValues: Data = Data((floatBuffer.lazy.map{
    //    UInt8(ImageProcessor.clamp((($0) + 1.0) * 128.0, minValue: 0.0, maxValue: 255.0))
    //})

    //simulating pixels from MLMultiArray
    //...
    let pixelValues = Data(count: 1*512*512) // <- ###

    var imageRef: CGImage?

    let bitsPerComponent = 8
    let bytesPerPixel = 1
    let bitsPerPixel = bytesPerPixel * bitsPerComponent
    let bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width

    let colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()
    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.none.rawValue)

    if let providerRef = CGDataProvider(data: pixelValues as CFData) { // <-###
        imageRef = CGImage(width: width,
                           height: height,
                           bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent,
                           bitsPerPixel: bitsPerPixel,
                           bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow,
                           space: colorSpaceRef,
                           bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo,
                           provider: providerRef,
                           decode: nil,
                           shouldInterpolate: false,
                           intent: CGColorRenderingIntent.defaultIntent)
    }

    newImage = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef!)

    return newImage
}
```

As far as I tried, this does not crash even in actual device with number of repeated touches. Please try. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: thank you very much for the help. Unfortunately I still get the same behaviour. The only thing I did was to replace the 'getSinglePlaneImage' function in the initially posted code with both of your suggestions: for the UInt8 version I always get the bad_access and with the Float32 one it randomly works from time to time, but most of the times I get the same error (just for a different address). Quicklook correctly displays the image before returning from the function and the crash only happens if I try to upload the image to the UIImageView.If I comment 'out.image=outImg' it works fine

Comment: @markwalberg, thanks for reporting. Unfortunately I cannot reproduce the same issue with my code (of course including `out.image=outImg`). If you can provide some info (build settings or target or something like that) about how to reproduce the issue or the whole project to reproduce the issue, I will work on it.

Comment: @markwalberg, thanks for providing the info. I could have reproduce the issue and I realized that I was missing the fact: `CGDataProvider.init(dataInfo:data:size:releaseData:)` holds the pointer `data` even after a `CGImage` is created. So, that's against the rule pointer passed from `withUnsafeBytes` is only valid while the closure is executing. Updating my answer, please check it later.

Comment: everything seems to be working just fine now. Thank you very much for the help